# Flip a pixel array horizontally

Tags: java, image, pixel, flip

I have the code to flip a 32 x 32 pixel array, but I have no idea how to flip it horizontally.

Here is the code for vertical flip.

```
for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
        newPixels[(i / 32) * 32
                + (i % 32)] = pixels[(32 - (i / 32) - 1) * Grid.SIZE + (i % 32)];
}
```

Since 32 is the width *and* height, it goes in all those places

Comment: This is very odd. `(i / 32) * 32 + (i % 32)` is just an obfuscated way of saying `i`. Can you explain the question in more detail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int imageWidth = 32;
for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
    newPixels[i] = pixels[i - 2 * (i % imageWidth) + imageWidth - 1];
}
```

The index used is the sum of `(i / imageWidth) * imageWidth` = `i - (i % imageWidth)` (the offset for the line) and `imageWidth - (i % imageWidth) - 1` (the x position mirrored at the center)

Comment: you wouldn't happen to have a formula for vertical as well? As well as horizontal AND vertical?